# Converting Sql server query to MySql query

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am trying to convert Query from sql server to MySql. My query in Sql is like below:

```
WITH ChildCategories (ParentID, categoryID, Level)
AS
(
    SELECT e.ParentID, e.CategoryID, 0 AS Level
    FROM dbo.Category AS e
    WHERE ParentID=195
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e.ParentID, e.CategoryID, Level + 1
    FROM dbo.Category AS e
    INNER JOIN ChildCategories AS d
        ON e.ParentID = d.categoryID
)
Select 195 as categoryID
UNION 
select CategoryID from ChildCategories
```

And I tried to convert above query in MySql like below:

```
select CategoryID, Name,( @pv:=t.ParentID,t.CategoryID) as ParentID 
    from (select CategoryID, Name, ParentID from Category order by CategoryID     desc) t 
    join (select @pv:=196)tmp on t.CategoryID=@pv 
    order by ParentID;
```

But am getting this error:

```
Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Can anyone help on this? Thanks in advance.